# Как добавить изображение главной страницы, и кнопки навигации в Google Snippet для мобильных?

Tags: javascript, html, seo, meta

[image: Картинка как справа]

[image: И вот такие кнопки навигации]

Итак 3 вопроса в одном!

1. Большая картинка справа
2. Маленькая картина снизу (favicon)
3. Кнопки навигации

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете пробовать использование **[PageMap от Гугл](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/1626952)**.

Для большой картинке (строну для показа определяет Гугл в зависимости от картинки - портрет или ланшафт, и от размера дисплея ввода информации) используйте **[PageMap для уменьшенных изображений](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/1626955)**, пример:

```html
<!--
<PageMap>
    <DataObject type="thumbnail">
      <Attribute name="src" value="http://www.example.com/recipes/applepie/applepie.jpg"/>
      <Attribute name="width" value="100"/>
      <Attribute name="height" value="130"/>
    </DataObject>
  </PageMap>
-->
```

Для иконки не уверен, что это может работать.

Для кнопок используйте **[Добавление действий](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/1628118)**, пример:

```html
<!--
<DataObject type="action">
   <Attribute name="label" value="Магазины"/>
   <Attribute name="url" value="http://listofstore.html"/>
   <Attribute name="class" value="название класса стилей который визуализирует кнопку"/>
</DataObject>
-->
```

Однако имеет смысл обратить внимание на тот факт что PageMap является частью **[Программируемой поисковой системы Гугл](https://support.google.com/programmable-search)** и будет ли это работать без созданной вами поисковой системы я не уверен.